# Angular multiple http requests

Tags: angular

I want to make a http call to the backend but before that, I need to get a oauth access token from the ID server. I think I have some syntax error. Am I doing it correctly?

```js
myFunction() {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('grant_type','password');
    params.append('client_id', "xxx");
    params.append('client_secret', 'yyy');

    params.append('username', 'zzz');
    params.append('password', 'aaa');


    let headers =
      new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'});

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/mytestrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      params.toString(), { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => {

          var headers2 = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.access_token
          });
          this.http.post("/api/list", params, {headers: headers2})
        }
        )
      )
}
```

This is a function in a service class
The calling side is to subscribe on the result

Comment: `params.toString()`, POST will be taking an Object.

Comment: Thanks @JsNgian but that's not an issue. I can do so if I just run one http call. I am not sure the syntax is correct to make multiple http calls sequentially. I got this error error TS2339: Property 'access_token' does not exist on type 'Object'.

39             'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.access_token

Comment: Tom, if you put a `console.log(res)` after the `tap` operator, what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```js
myFunction() {
    // URLSearchParams can be create from an object (readability)
    let params = new URLSearchParams({
      'grant_type': 'password',
      'client_id': "xxx",
      'client_secret': 'yyy',
      'username': 'zzz',
      'password': 'aaa'
    });

    const headers =
      new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'});

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/mytestrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      params.toString(), { headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError((err, caught) => /* Logic in case the request for token errors */),
        map((res) => {
          if (res.hasOwnProperty('access_token') {
            new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.access_token
            }),
          } else {
            throw new Error('No token');
          }
        }),
        // switchMap will perform the request and return the result
        switchMap(headers => this.http.post("/api/list", params, {headers})),
        catchError((err, caught) => /* Logic in case the previous request errors */)
      )
}
```

Comment: I still have compilation error on res.access_token. Do I declare an object instead of using "res"? And the calling data source is throwing compilation error as well 

 No overload matches this call.
33       .subscribe((result: MyResponse) => {

Comment: could you elaborate on why you do not use a `mergeMap`

Comment: I am still new to Angular. Can you show me an example? Just FYI, if I just do noe call like this, it all compiled

return this.http.post<MyResponse>("/api/list", params , {headers : headers});

Comment: Just a thought: are you using a proxy for `/api/list`? If not, the full url for your backend is required (which would change your second post request to `this.http.post('http://localhost:backendPort/.../api/list'`)

Comment: Yes, I am using a proxy for the second URL. The first one is a call to ID server so no proxy

Comment: You could add a guard to check if `res` has the `access_token` proerty (see edit)

Comment: I cannot compile that either in Intellji. Is there a way to make two HTTP call in sequence and return the resultset to the caller?